# How to start "Spring Tool Suite 4" IDE from macOS terminal

Tags: terminal, macos-big-sur, spring-tools-4

Is there any command to launch a program using Spring Tool Suite 4 IDE without leaving the terminal (macOS)? For example, "code" for VS Code. You can type " code name_of_file "on terminal to open name_of_file on VS Code.

Comment: maybe related to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564340

Comment: the workaround mentioned in that bug worked for me, btw.